# Why was Roy McBride fed through a tube into his belly during the long distance space flights in Ad Astra?

Tags: space, ad-astra

In the movie Ad Astra we can see that Brad Pitt's character Roy McBride connects a tube into his belly and feeds himself (which makes him feel nasty) through it. It was after he departed from Mars, to reach Saturn as I remember.

Why was that necessary?

Comment: I'm at a loss how this has attracted a vote for being "opinion-based".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line from the screenplay was omitted from the film. Roy is going to spend the journey **under sedation**, hence he cannot feed himself during this time.

> **ROY MCBRIDE:** *Destination, Neptune Moon Galatea coordinates.*
>
> **COMPUTER VOICE:** *Length of journey: 19 days, 4 hours, 8 minutes.
> **Sedation is advised.***
>
> Roy HOOKS HIMSELF UP to a FEED TUBE, into his arm. He BUCKLES HIMSELF
> IN, and straps start sending ELECTRICAL PULSES to his body, to keep
> his muscles in some sort of tone. Roy SETTLES IN, and the ROCKETS
> ALIGHT... He is on his way...
>
> <sub><sup>[Ad Astra - Original Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/ad-astra-2019.pdf)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

Why was it necessary to feed himself?  If he does not feed himself he will die.

Why was it necessary to attach a tube?  Fairly certain there is no canon answer and to be fair this might be more suited to a space travel exchange if such a thing exists

That being said a few possibilities exist

maybe his throat hurt and he did not feel like eating.

maybe injecting food makes it easier to digest meaning you need less of it to get your nutrients and space is ironically at a premium on a space ship.

Comment: This question was posted on space stack exchange already and closed for being off topic there. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49115/should-astranauts-be-feeded-through-a-tube-into-belly-during-long-distance-space